# I keep getting this error code saying no such file or directory

Tags: python

```
= RESTART: C:\Users\rocky\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\computeAverageYears.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rocky\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\computeAverageYears.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open('cars.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cars.csv'
```

I got this error code, and I don't know how to fix it. This is code I got from a teacher for an assignment so this part should be working but for the life of me, I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

I tried moving the cars.csv file to different places on my computer as well as specifying the path to that file and nothing.

Comment: Show us you code and file structure!

Comment: Did you create a file `cars.csv` with the data that you want to read? Is it in your current folder (which may not be the same folder as the code)?

Comment: `cars.csv` does not exist **in the current directory**.  The current directory is NOT necessarily the same directory as the python script.  You can use this code to display the actual current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`